# how to specify data storage path for specific mongodb database

Tags: mongodb, storage

I have two storage devices. how can I create two databases and store each databases files in separate hard drive. the reason is, one of them are faster and I want to store normal data on it and another is slower and should be used as archive.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. we can enable storage.directoryPerDb in mongod.conf:

```
storage:
  directoryPerDb: true
...
```

this will create each database's files in a directory. and then mount your desired hard drive at that directory. do not forget to CHMOD and CHGRP the directory to user and group of your mongodb.